# Streamlabs API 405 response code

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, python-requests

I'm trying to use [Streamlabs API](https://dev.streamlabs.com/). Streamlabs API uses Oauth2 for creating apps. So first I send whoever's using my app to an authorization link containing my app's client id and the scopes I want to use.
*(Something like this:* streamlabs.com/api/v1.0/authorize?client_id=CLIENT-ID-HERE&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code&scope=SOME+SCOPES+HERE)

Once I've done that I receive a code at the redirect uri specified. I then use that code to get the access token for permanent access to the connected user's account. I then receive the access token from a POST request that works perfectly... Now I run into the problem. When getting the temporary code before the access token I specified the scopes: **"donations.read +donations.create+alerts.write+alerts.create"**.

When authorizing, the app asks for permission to the different scopes. The scope in focus is **"alerts.write"** so that I can send test alerts using POST requests. But this doesn't work for some reason. To send a test alert I have to send a POST request to this url: **"https://streamlabs.com/api/alerts/send_test_alert"**

I've tried doing that in two different ways.
**1:**

```
import requests

url = "https://streamlabs.com/api/alerts/send_test_alert"

data = {
    "access_token":"UserAccessTokenHere",
    "type":"donation"
}

response = requests.post(url=url, data=data)

print(response.text)
```

2:

```
import requests

url = "https://streamlabs.com/api/alerts/send_test_alert?access_token=UserAccessTokenHere&type=donation"

response = requests.post(url=url)

print(response.text)
```

If I do `print(response)` it prints "Response [405]".
But if I do `print(response.text)` I get a long HTML document for this page: [Error response page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOhRp.png)

Any ideas what's going wrong with my Python requests? send_test_alert documentation here: [Link](https://dev.streamlabs.com/v1.0/reference#alertssend_test_alert)

Comment: My exact problem.

Comment: Try using GET for the final step. The 405 message indicates that POST is not allowed to that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've contacted support and looks like you've made the same error as me.

You're not actually sending a request to the right URL.
You are a sending a request to: "https://streamlabs.com/api/alerts/send_test_alert"

You should be using the URL: "https://streamlabs.com/api/**v1.0**/alerts/send_test_alert"