# How do you allow other users to access your Streamlabs API app?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0

The documentation isn't perfectly clear on this, I am able to hardcode in my token and get it to work as such

```
const socketToken = 'mytokenrandomlongstringofchars';

//Connect to socket
const streamlabs = io(`https://sockets.streamlabs.com?token=${socketToken}`, {
      transports: ['websocket']
 });
```

Then listen in for events as such

```
streamlabs.on("event", (eventData) => {
      if (eventData.for === "streamlabs" && eventData.type == "donation") {
        var donobj = eventData.message;
        var dononame = donobj[0].from;
        var donomessage = donobj[0].message;
        document.getElementById("alert-message").innerHTML = dononame;
        document.getElementById("alert-user-message").innerHTML = donomessage;
        console.log(donobj);
      }
    });
```

The API uses oAuth 2 to allow users to connect and this is where I'm stuck and the snippets in the documentation aren't exactly helping, I'm supposed to send the user to an authorization link that looks something like this

*streamlabs.com/api/v1.0/authorize?client_id=CLIENT-ID-HERE&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code&scope=SOME+SCOPES+HERE*

as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50623935/streamlabs-api-405-response-code) stack overflow answser, then once they accept the authorization they are redirected by to the redirect uri that I specified when registering the app alongside a code, that looks something like this

*my.site/callback?code=randomstringofcharacters*.

I'm supposed to send a POST request to https://streamlabs.com/api/v1.0/token with that code to get an access token, then use that access token to send a GET request to https://streamlabs.com/api/v1.0/socket/token so that I can finally get the web socket token that I could use to listen for events, where I have no clue where to procede is how to get the code from the redirected URL, if I'm understanding the process correctly then I should be able to manage the other steps, but how to I get the code in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are asking for, but you can add authorized users on the streamlabs website, under the app settings. Let me know if I need to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

For donation alerts I created an App, that works fine. I am sharing the code here:-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if(Session["Resp"]!=null)
    {
        LBL2.Text=Session["Resp"].ToString();
        return;
    }
    int c=0;
    try
    {
        if (Session["Counter"] == null)
            Session.Add("Counter", 0);
        else{
            c = int.Parse(Session["Counter"].ToString()) + 1;
        }
        lbl1.Text = c.ToString();
        string CD = Request.QueryString["CODE"].ToString();
        code.Value = CD;
        form1.Method = "POST";
        //form1.Action = "https://streamlabs.com/api/v1.0/token";
        form1.Action = "https://streamlabs.com/api/v2.0/token";


        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
                    | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;

            byte[] response =
            client.UploadValues("https://streamlabs.com/api/v2.0/token", new NameValueCollection()
           {
               { "client_id", client_id.Value },
               { "client_secret", client_secret.Value },
               { "redirect_uri", redirect_uri.Value },
               { "code", CD },
               { "grant_type", grant_type.Value },
           });

            string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
            token deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<token>(result);
            LBL2.Text = result;
            tok.Text = deserializedProduct.access_token;
        }

            
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
    }
    //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();  
}
```

Save this file as accesstoken.aspx, Run this code setting the Port (in visual studio) at 1280, and Set the redirect url in Streamlabs app to http://localhost:1280/accesstoken.aspx . Then run the TryIt link from the streamlabs app while visual studio is running. The AccessToken would be received.
Then I used that access token for donation creation.
Please Note: The StreamLabs Application that you create needs to be approved by them.

The Donation Code I used:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (acctok == null || acctok.Length < 20)
        {
            Lbl1.Text = "No accesstoken";
            return;
        }

        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
                    | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;

            client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + acctok);
            client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
            client.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
            //client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            string response = client.UploadString("https://streamlabs.com/api/v2.0/donations","POST", retJson2(txtName.Text, decimal.Parse(txtAmt.Text)));
            string result = response;   // System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
            RetData2 deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RetData2>(result);
            Lbl1.Text = deserializedProduct.donation_id;

        }
    }
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.